# How to solve the "Bignum out of Float range" warning?

Tags: ruby

Running this code:

```
n = 4 * 1000 * 1000
fn = (((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) ** n) - ((1 - Math.sqrt(5)) ** n)) / ((2 ** n) * Math.sqrt(5))
puts fn - 1
```

I get the warning

> **Bignum out of Float range**

How can I fixed my code to solve this error?

Since ruby is dynamically typed, I don't know how. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ruby has types. In fact, ruby is a strongly typed (as opposed to weak) language, meaning that every single object has a well defined type. It is also a dynamically typed language (as opposed to statically) which it think is what you're referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html).

---

Something like this may work (*I let it run for a minute on my machine and it still hadn't come up with an answer... seems to computationally expensive*):

```
require "bigdecimal"

n       = (4 * 1000 * 1000)
sqr_5   = BigDecimal("5.0").sqrt(5)
sqr_5a1 = BigDecimal((1+sqr_5).to_s)
sqr_5m1 = BigDecimal((sqr_5-1).to_s) 
fn      = (sqr_5a1.power(n) - (sqr_5m1.power(n))) / ((2.power(n)) * sqr_5)
puts fn - 1
```